# Which one is acceptable in an academic paper? Fig 4. show or Fig 4. shows?

Tags: grammar, articles, writing, publishing

Is it right to say:

> Fig. 4, **Show** the wireless transmission of data.

Shouldn't it be:

> Fig. 4, **Shows** the wireless transmission of data.

By the way, another question would be, is it right to use both of mentioned forms in an academic paper? I mean, some one writes *Fig. 4, shows* in a paragraph and in another, in the same paper, writes *Fig. 4, show*?

Comment: Figure 4, no matter how it is written, refers to one item.  Therefore its verb is always singular and has an s at the end. Fig. 4 shows something, Fig. 4 and 5 show something.

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct form is:

> **Fig. 4 shows** the wireless transmission of data.

No comma after 4 and lowercase shows.

Comment: Thank you, what about my second question?

Comment: No, the form I showed above should be used throughout the paper.